# Mock a controller error in c# unit testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am trying to create different types of errors in an ASP.NET controller (which communicates with a service). Right now I am focusing on a ServiceNotFound error, but `DbContextMock()` always returns true. What is the correct way to do this?

(In OrdersController.cs)

```
    public OrdersController(IOrdersService ordersService)
    {
        _ordersService = ordersService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(ordersService));
    }

    [HttpPut]
    [ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.NoContent)]
    [ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PutOrdersAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            await _ordersService.PutOrdersAsync();

            return new StatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status204NoContent);
        }
        catch (ServiceException ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(
                (int)ex.StatusCode,
                Responses.ErrorResponse with { Message = ex.Message, Content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ex), RequestId = Request.HttpContext.Connection.Id }
            );
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(
                StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError,
                Responses.ErrorResponse with { Message = ex.Message, Content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ex), RequestId = Request.HttpContext.Connection.Id }
            );
        }
    }
```

(In Tests.cs)

```
        ...
        var context = new DbContextMock();
        ...
        var service = GetOrdersService(context.Object, _pdcClientFactory.Object);
        ...
        await service.PutOrdersAsync();
```

Comment: Don't really understand your approach. One tip I will give is don't give every action a try / catch and write middleware which will do just this. Because the implementation of you try catch will probably be the same in almost every action

Comment: Please clarify which object you wish to test (controller/service), and provide full test code

Comment: Opal unfortunately I can't give the full test code because it's private software.  I am trying to test if the Service Exception gets thrown. I just don't know where to begin, so I doubt my test would be of any help anyways.